# Python MySQLdb: combine 2 tables,select data as dict. I am confused about the dict's key

Tags: python, mysql

I have two tables:user and post

and the structures of them are:

post:

```
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

user:

```
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email   | char(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

i get this:(keys of data dict)

```
['post.user_id', 'user_id', 'name', 'email', 'post.name', 'id']
```

my python code is:

```
import MySQLdb

import MySQLdb.cursors

con = MySQLdb.connect(user = "root", passwd = "123456", db = "mydb",   cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from user, post where user.user_id = post.user_id")

print cur.fetchone().keys()
```

but,**why the keys of data dict is that**? thanks. My English is not so well,excuse me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select *, you ask for all columns in both user and post. Since user and post have columns with overlapping names, the tablename is added before a few of them, to create unique keys.

I'm not sure what you were expecting, but you can explicitly control the keys you get by giving the columns aliases:

"select user.user_id as user_id, post.name as post_name, user.name as user_name ..."

Comment: thank you. I want to know why some column is:table.name         and others are name (without table)

Comment: MySQLdb (or the DictCursor) is doing that for you. If you try to put two columns with the same name into a dictionary, the column names will collide. MySQL returns the columns in the order that the tables were specified (user, post) and when adding post.name, MySQLdb observes that a key "name" already exists in the dictionary, so it uses the key post.name instead. If you would rather have the user table added, you can specify your tables in reverse order (post, user) and then you will get ['user.user_id', 'user_id', 'name', 'email', 'user.name', 'id']